# How to prevent numberformatexception here?

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm

So I'm making a GA and I have this code to set the solution:

```
public static void setSolution(String s) {
    s=s.replaceAll("\\s","");
    try{
        int val = Integer.parseInt(s);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e){
        System.out.println("Not a number");
    }
    geneLength = s.length();
    for(int i=0; i<geneLength; i++){
        solution[i] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i,i));
    }
}
```

How do I prevent it from throwing the exception because I tried using the try catch block but it doesn't work

Comment: So if it isn't a number then maybe just return? You would need to put that in the `catch` block

Comment: Ah thank you very much :)

Comment: Now it works when it's not a number but when I try to set the solution as a number it still throws the exception at me. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Your substring will always return an empty String.

Change

```
Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i));
```

to

```
Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i, i + 1));
```

This will return a String with a length of 1, rather than 0.